# Redirect traffic when Firebase Hosting is down

Tags: firebase, dns, cdn, firebase-hosting

I know by experience that with load balancers **L7** we can redirect traffic to others endpoints if applications become *unhealthy*.

As Firebase Hosting is using **CDN** to deliver static content, is there a way to redirect traffic if this static content becomes unavailable?

I thought of using **DNS rules** that uses redirect but I am concerned about the propagation time that may be too much. (and that could even take more time then Google resolving the incident)

Is there a way to manage that with this service or should I switch to another kind of architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on your DNS manager itself, Firebase Hosting is delivered via Fastly and if Fastly is down, a good ~30% of the internet is down in general. This was seen a few weeks ago when multiple social media sites and apps broke. As such, you should ensure your host is not on Fastly as the first condition.

From there, you would have to manage some basic logic through a 3rd party DNS manager. A popular one is Cloud Flare which allows the configuration of load balancer pools where if your primary pool is unavailable, you can connect to your backup pool (costs do apply)

- https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/create-load-balancer-ui